# How to get a part of the url using aiohttp_jinja2?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, aiohttp

So I am trying to get a part of the URL like `http://example/home?code=123456789` this `123456789` changes every time since it is oauth
so I am trying to get it

This is the py file

```py
from aiohttp import web,  web_urldispatcher

import discord
from discord.ext import commands


import aiohttp_jinja2

import jinja2
from pathlib import Path


from oauth import Ouath


        @aiohttp_jinja2.template('home.html')
        async def start(request):
            raise web.HTTPSeeOther(location=Ouath.discord_login_url)



        @aiohttp_jinja2.template('home.html')
        async def login(request):
           return
        app = web.Application(loop=self.client.loop)
        aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(str(here)))
        app.router.add_get('/', start)
        app.router.add_get('/home', login)
        runner = web.AppRunner(app)
        await runner.setup()
        self.site = web.TCPSite(runner, '127.0.0.1', 5000)
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()
        await self.site.start()
```

i want to print it in the html file
but i don't know how to get that part
note: i edit the code box

Comment: if you have string `url = "http://example/home?code=123456789"` then you can `url.split('?code=')[-1]` or if number is always at the end and it has always the same lenght `url[-9:]`. But there is also `urllib.parse` and `urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlsplit('http://example/home?code=123456789').query)` gives dictionary `{'code': ['123456789']}`

Comment: it will work but for me it won't cuz when i login via discord it adds that code randomly and it's not with fixed also it changes if i logged in again or according to the user

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `web` from `aiohttp` you can add a route that accepts a parameter

```
routes = web.RouteTableDef()
@routes.get('/guild/{guild}')
async def guild(request):
    gid = request.match_info['guild']
```

The url would be `http://localhost:PORT/guild/123456`
Once you've fetched the required details, you're free to render a template or return a response.

Comment: the problem is that `?code=123456789` is added when i login my website with my discord acc and it changes every time so if i did what u told me to it will be like `http://example.com/guild/server.name?code=145623789`

Answer (score 1):

If you have string then you can use

```
URL = 'http://example/home?code=123456789'

code = URL.split('?code=')[-1]
```

or if number is always at the end and it has always the same lenght

```
URL = 'http://example/home?code=123456789'

code = URL[-9:]
```

But there is also `urllib.parse` and

```
URL = 'http://example/home?code=123456789'

data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlsplit(URL).query)
```

gives dictionary

```
{'code': ['123456789']}
```

and you can do

```
code = data.get('code')
```

and it will gives expected `code` or `None` if there was no `?code=...` in url.

---

**EDIT** Probably you have to use `request.url`

```
@aiohttp_jinja2.template('home.html') 
async def login(request): 
     data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlsplit(request.url).query)
     code = data.get('code')
     return {'code': code}
```

Because `data` is dictionary with `"code"` so you could use `return data`

```
@aiohttp_jinja2.template('home.html') 
async def login(request): 
     data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlsplit(request.url).query)
     return data
```

Comment: it will work but for me it won't cuz when i login via discord it adds that code randomly and it's not with fixed also it changes if i logged in again or according to the user

Comment: first method and specialy third method should work with any number in url. Third method should works even if there are other variables in url.

Comment: so `urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlsplit('http://example/home?code=123456789').query)` will get me the number what ever is it ?

Comment: you have to get current URL and use it in `urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlsplit(CURRENT_URL).query)` and it should gives you `code` from current URL.

Comment: yeah the problem is how do i get the current url when it changes everytime i login via discord plus do i pip install urllib? or is it in aiohttp?

Comment: ```
 @aiohttp_jinja2.template('home.html')
        async def login(request):
           code =  urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlsplit(request).query)
            return {'code': code}
``` like this ?

Comment: thanks man and sorry i don't use stackoverflow much so i didn't know

Answer (score 1):

After digging in source code of `aiohttp_jinja2` and `aiohttp` it seems you can get it with `request.query.get('code')`

```
@aiohttp_jinja2.template('home.html') 
async def login(request): 
    #print('code:', request.query.get('code'))
    return {'code': request.query.get('code')}
```

If there is not `?code=...` in URL then it gives `None` but you can set other default value using `request.query.get('code', some_default_value)`

---

Doc `aiohttp`: [web.BaseRequest.query](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.BaseRequest.query)

Answer (score 0):

```py
@aiohttp_jinja2.template('home.html') 
async def login(request): 
code = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlsplit(request).query)
return {'code': code}
```

like this ?

Comment: first: it is place for answers/solutions - it this code doesn't resolve your problem then it is not place for this code. Better put code in your question or eventually use portals like pastebin.org . Second: first try, next ask. I don't have `aiohttp_jinja2` so I don't know what you get in `request` but if this is not URL then it will not work. You should check what you get with `print(request)` I would exepect that you may need `request.url` or maybe there is even `request.query` or `request.args` (like in `Flask`) or `request.query` and then you may already get all parameters as dictionary.

Comment: I digg in source code of `aiohttp_jinja2` and `request` and it seems it has [request.query](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.BaseRequest.query) which should gives you dictionary so maybe you can do `request.query.get('code')` or `request.query['code']`